# HTML content from the web is only partially obtained/displayed

Tags: java, android

I am running a downloaded tested code from an Android app development course by Rob Percival in Android studio.

The code is for fetching HTML content of a specified URL and displaying it in the logs.

It's the tested code provided by the author of the course.

The code runs fine but only a part of the HTML content of the specified URL is displayed in the logs.

These are the additional log entries I'm getting:

(After displaying partial html content)

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 81(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 43(11MB) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.012ms total 115.686ms
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa63c98c0, tid 10451
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa63c9d80, tid 10487
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa83cdf20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa83cdf20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa84e32d0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa83cdf20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa84e32d0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.